# installing openstack on ubuntu in vm

Tags: cloud, openstack

I am completely new to openstack. I am having a few doubts regarding openstack. Googling about it didn't help me. I am doing a project on implementing a private cloud using Openstack. My final goal is that I should be able to run openstack on two systems, one acting as a server and the other as a client. The client should be able to access the instances. I have managed to install openstack and configured it. I can now access horizon on each system. Now the problem is, I want to connect the other system and access the same dashboard. I don't understand what are controller and compute nodes. Should both these nodes be installed on the same system? how can I get the desired private cloud system? Please excuse me if I sound dumb. Please kindly help me guys.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. You should try asking that on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: thank you for you suggestion @DiogoRocha. I've tried asking at various sites but i didn't get any reply. so i am asking it here.

Comment: [askubuntu] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/700472/openstack-lan-setup) my question on Ask Ubuntu. If anyone could answer, please answer it.

Comment: https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/openstack-services.html try this link. You need a better understanding before starting.

Comment: to start with openstack, first understand the basics of it and if you want to install the same follow this link from official guide of openstack https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/